# Karaf wants optional imports?

Tags: apache-karaf, apache-felix, moxy, bnd

I'm trying to use org.eclipse.persistence.moxy 2.7.4 in Karaf.

Karaf 4.2.6 is saying:

```
Error executing command: Error executing command on bundles:
        Error starting bundle 71: Unable to resolve HelloWorld [71](R 71.0): missing requirement [HelloWorld [71](R 71.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (osgi.wiring.package=com.sun.codemodel) Unresolved requirements: [[HelloWorld [71](R 71.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (osgi.wiring.package=com.sun.codemodel)]
```

I think this is because moxy's META-INF includes:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.persistence.moxy
Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.persistence.core;bundle-version="2.7.4";visibility:=reexport,org.eclipse.persistence.asm;bundle-version="7.0.0" ;resolution:=optional
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Vendor: Eclipse.org - EclipseLink Project
Import-Package: com.sun.xml.bind;resolution:=optional,com.sun.xml.bind.annotation;resolution:=optional,com.sun.xml.bind.api;resolution:=optional,com.sun.xml.bind.api.impl;resolution:=optional,com.sun.codemodel;resolution:=optional;version="[2.2.11,3)"
Bundle-Name: EclipseLink MOXy
Bundle-Version: 2.7.4.v20190115-ad5b7c6b2a
```

Note `com.sun.codemodel;resolution:=optional;version="[2.2.11,3)`

But it says "resolution:=optional".  So why is this an unresolved requirement, and how can I make karaf treat it as optional?

Answer (score 0):

Note that here, it's not moxy that complains about not finding that package, but your own service. Check your `Import-Package` in your `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF`, it's possible that if you use maven-bundle-plugin, the dependency is scanned thanks to your pom.xml and then inferred in your `Import-Package` clause.